# grunt-contrib-sass generates one file instead of multiple files

Tags: sass, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-sass

For some reason grunt-contrib-sass generates a combined `.css` file instead of multiple `.css` files. But this only happens when I define the `ext` option.

**File structure:**

`app/
    assets/
        stylesheets/
            application.web.scss
            application.mobile.scss
            application.tablet.scss
    public/
        assets/`

**Gruntfile.js Config**

`sass: {
    default: {
        options: {
            compass: false,
            noCache: true,
            style: 'expanded'
        },
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            src: 'application.**.scss',
            dest: 'public/assets',
            cwd: 'app/assets/stylesheets',
            ext: '.css'
        }]
    }
}`

The above configuration generates the following:

`app/
    assets/
        stylesheets/
            application.web.scss
            application.mobile.scss
            application.tablet.scss
    public/
        assets/
            application.css`

If I remove the `ext` option completely it generates:

`app/
    assets/
        stylesheets/
            application.web.scss
            application.mobile.scss
            application.tablet.scss
    public/
        assets/
            application.web.scss
            application.mobile.scss
            application.tablet.scss`

What I want it to generate is:

`app/
    assets/
        stylesheets/
            application.web.scss
            application.mobile.scss
            application.tablet.scss
    public/
        assets/
            application.web.css
            application.mobile.css
            application.tablet.css`

I know I'm probably overlooking a very basic thing, but I cannot seem to solve this for the life of me XD So any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You do understand that every client will download every linked CSS file, even if they do not meet the media conditions, right?  The user does not benefit from this.

Comment: You do know that compiling SCSS files into multiple files has nothing to do with the linked CSS right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem was that the filenames contained multiple dots. And this gets confused with the extension. To fix this I was supposed to use the `extDot` attribute to define on which dot does the extension start. I found this answer here https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/pull/863#issuecomment-22015455 which points to the actual documentation here http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically